# Is there a way to make sparkjava have a restful java API similar to dropwizard?

Tags: java, rest, spark-java

My team is looking into using sparkjava for a RESTful webservice but I'm not happy with the options for deserializing requests.

It seems like the options are either:

1. Use its default deserialization which just provides a nested map structure, which defeats the purpose of using an OO language like Java
2. Wrap every path definition in a bunch of boilerplate in order to deserialize/serialize the request and response objects and invoke a handler method.

I've written some stuff to reduce the amount of boilerplate, so you can write something like:

```
    public void Routes() {
        post("/happy/birthday", (request, response) -> {
            return callJson(getHandler("birthday"), request, response);
        });
    }
```

Which isn't bad, but it requires reflection to look up the birthday method so there isn't a compile-time validation that the birthday handler method exists.  But it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: My personal opinion:
Automatic marshalling and unmarshalling of parameters (query or payload) like in JAX-RS is the reason why I'm not switching to SparkJava.
Started a project with SparkJava, was enthusiast at the beginning. After a couple months and 5k lines of code, turned out to be unmanageable for a medium personal project. 
Switched to jax-rs, more verbose at the beginning, much maintainable at the end

Comment: I found myself writing code for abstracting the marshalling, decoupling routes from resources (not mine article, but relevant https://www.deadcoderising.com/sparkjava-separating-routing-and-resources/) or dynamically marshalling json/xml based on request header.
After weeks, I found myself writing most of the built-in features in jax-rs. 
Switched to Jersey + Grizzly, not looking back, but still missing the initial beauty and simplicity of SparkJava code

Answer (score 0):

Might be misunderstanding something, but Spark Java is just Java so you can use any Java serialization library.  I have used Gson with Spark.

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  post("/employee", (request, response) -> {
     ValidateNewEmployeeCommand command = new ValidateNewEmployeeCommand();
     Employee emp = gson.fromJson(request.body(), Employee.class);
     return command.validateEmployee(emp);
  }, gson::toJson);
```

Comment: Yeah it's probably a pretty minor nitpick but the idea was to reduce the amount of boilerplate.  A member of my team managed to cook up something so that a post can be defined as:


    `EmployeeController c = new EmployeeController();
    post("/hello", Employee.class, e::validateEmployee);`

Answer (score 0):

Livy (Apache License) is a service that enables remote apps to easily interact with a Spark cluster over a REST API. It enables easy submission of Spark jobs or snippets of Spark code, synchronous or asynchronous result retrieval, and SparkContext management, all via a simple REST interface or an RPC client library. Livy also simplifies interaction between Spark and application servers, streamlining the architecture needed for interactive web/mobile applications.

With Livy, you can also:

Use long-running SparkContexts for multiple Spark jobs, by multiple clients

Manage multiple SparkContexts simultaneously, and run them on the cluster (YARN/Mesos) instead of the Livy Server for good fault tolerance and concurrency

Submit jobs as precompiled jars, snippets of code, or via Java/Scala client API

Ensure security via secure authenticated communication (work in progress)

To use Livy, Spark must be installed on your server (1.4 or later; Scala 2.10 builds). To get started, [download/install packages from here](http://archive.cloudera.com/beta/livy/livy-server-0.2.0.zip) and then just do the following:

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/07/livy-the-open-source-rest-service-for-apache-spark-joins-cloudera-labs/

Comment: Unfortunately sparkjava is confusingly named - it's a separate product from Apache Spark.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no way to achieve quite what I was aiming for, but we've cooked up some utilities that will do the job for us and allow us to define routes the same way they're defined in Dropwizard.  We'll see if we can open source it.